# display data from related tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables one is books and the other is writer. They are related through one to many relationship i.e. the primary key in writer i.e. w_id is foreign key in books named by b_writer. but when i print the b_writer in php script, it prints the id i.e a number, but i want the name of the writer. How can i do it?

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecom");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE b_id = '".$_POST["book_id"]."'";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    echo $row["b_id"] $row["b_desc"] $row["b_name"] $row["b_writer"];
}
```

How can i print the name of the writer when i print the `b_writer`.

Comment: You need a JOIN: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use a join for get the data form both the tables eg:

```
"SELECT b.*, w.* 
 FROM books as b
 INNER JOIN writer as w on b.b_writer = w.w_id
 WHERE b_id = '".$_POST["book_id"]."'";
```

but be careful with the use of var in query you are at risk of sqlinjection

for avoid this 
You should use prepare statement and binding param eg:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT b.*, w.* 
  FROM books as b
  INNER JOIN writer as w on b.b_writer = w.w_id
  WHERE b_id =?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["book_id"] );
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

use join

change your query

```
select a.*,b.* from book as a inner join writer b on a.b_id = b.id where b_id = '".$_POST["book_id"]."'
```

Comment: all of the queries are still displaying the id of the writer rather than its name